# Using a CDN with the new azure storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an existing (classic) storage account which i have a cdn pointed to. I recently created a new Storage account via the new portal (not classic storage). It seems that its not possible to add a CDN via either old or new portal to point the this new storage account. Is this possible via a powershell script possibly and if so are there any pointers as to how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Azure CDN isn't supported in PowerShell yet](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-create-new-endpoint/#comment-2138332717). CDN isn't supported in the preview portal yet. This will prevent you from deploying CDN using V2 storage.